# How to change "system" drive to another

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I'm in deep trouble here (4 a.m. local time should give u some idea).

My HDD has a primary partition and an extended partition with 3 logical drives in it. My problem is related to C and D drives only. My C drive had Windows 7 (32-bit) on it. I then installed Win7 (64-bit) on D drive. For ease, let's call C as W32 and D as W64 drive. I'm assigning them names becuz when I boot into Win64, my C drive is displayed there as D and D as C, so let's just call them W32 and W64 for ease. So here is the config:

```
Disk     System    Boot    Type                 OS
=====    ======    ====    ====                 ==
W32       Yes       Yes    Primary              Windows 7 (32-bit)
W64       No        Yes    Extended/Logical     Windows 7 (64-bit)
```

Now I finally happened to settle for 64-bit and wanted to get rid of 32-bit version. I booted into Win64. I cleaned most of the stuff on W32 drive including Windows folder, Program Files and other things and then tried to format it, which failed because Windows didn't want to format a "system" drive. I tried to convert my W64 drive into Primary partition but that wasn't allowed either because a logical drive cannot be converted into Primary.

What is my way forward? All I want is just to get rid of W32 drive and set my W64 drive as primary/active/boot/system.

Comment: Did you mean you booted into W32 and cleaned most of the stuff on W64 drive?

Comment: @Alex: No, I mean I booted into W64 and cleaned most of W32 (my system disk) contents.

Comment: @Alex: Edited my question. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Windows 7 on a logical drive you cannot operate because you cannot put the bootmgr on it. For that you need an active primary partition. Your bootmgr is still on the 32bit drive and if you delete that, your system will not boot.

What you can try is the following:

1. Download the iso of the **[bootable CD of partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html)**
2. Burn that iso to CD
3. Boot your PC with that CD
4. Try to convert the 64bit partition to primary. See picture below. I do recommend to make an image of that partition first - just in case.
5. Boot your 64 partition and **[copy the bootmgr to C](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/209885-bootmgr-move-c-easybcd.html)** (C is always the running OS).
6. Check in Disk Management whether your 64bit partition is the **active** partition now.

If you have problems along the way, post back

[image]